# What is the difference between vorlesen and mitlesen?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar-identification

Those two words vorlesen and mitlesen both mean to read in english. What is the difference?.

i.e:

- Lies den Brief noch einmal vor!
- Lesen Sie mit!

Comment: https://dict.leo.org/german-english/mitlesen and https://dict.leo.org/german-english/vorlesen

Answer (score 3):

*vorlesen* → to read (out) aloud; to read to sb.

*mitlesen* → to read along

---

<sup>Source: any dictionary (see, e.g., [this](https://www.dict.cc/?s=vorlesen) and [that](https://www.dict.cc/?s=mitlesen) entry at [www.dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc)), which is why the question is actually off-topic.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

vorlesen means someone reads something for you, for example:

> meine Mutter liest mir eine Gutenachtgeschichte vor

mitlesen means read together with someone, for example:

> in der Schule lesen wir das Gedicht mit dem Lehrer mit

Answer (score 1):

> Those two words vorlesen and mitlesen both mean to read in english. What is the difference?

The best answer I can give you without seeing some concrete context sentences is

- *vorlesen* means to *read* and speak out loud what you're at at the same time
- *mitlesen* means to listen and *read* at the same time what you're hearing

Answer (score 1):

The difference of vorlesen and mitlesen is in the different situation and can be explained  by the different meanings of the prefixes vor- and mit-

It is the same difference as :vormachen / mitmachen or vorspielen / mitspielen.

In all 3 situations

the prefix vor- means to show / to  demonstrate / to performe something to someone.

It  will be always be aloud in font of a public or audience, except someone is reading aloud read aloud to himself,

the prefix mit- means to join / take part in something.

Comment: Das lässt sich aber nicht verallgemeinern. Ein Gegenbeispiel wäre _vornehmen_ / _mitnehmen_.

Comment: da hast du recht. darum habe ich nur diese drei Bsp. genommen, die  mit einer performance zusammen hängen.

Comment: Sie können ja dazu schreiben, dass es Ausnahmen gibt.